# validating an xml document against the rules defined and finding the line of error in the document

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an xml document , which I convert it into a  class and validate it for some conditions that I have defined in my code . if there is an error in the xml document i.e if the xml document doesn't satisfy all the requirements that i have defined in the code it gives an error . Now I want to know in which line in xml the error has occurred.

how can i do this ? Need some ideas ?

Comment: Please show your code - Stack Overflow does not issue crystal balls and no one here is clairvoyant. :)

Comment: the code is pretty big . i ll give an example .For the given xml file.it has tags like <Name><Age><Description> im checking if the description is of specific format , if not my code raises error. i want to know in whicn line the error is .?

Comment: What are you using to parse the XML file?  XPath?  LINQ to XML? Something else?

Comment: Its not anyof it ..i am parsing with my own logic

Comment: Then you'll need to keep track of where you are in the XML during the parsing if you want to identify the line the error is on.  Without seeing the code you're using to parse, it's very difficult to give you a better answer.